# Cognitive Services Speech Container: Unable to download custom models

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

I've been using a speech container for a few months now without any problem. But now I have trained a new model with the latest baseline and I'm unable to make the docker download it:

```
Starting custom model download
2020/05/20 11:29:06 Preparing file /usr/local/models/0_FR_FR_V2.4_S2S/adaptedPrepAM/model.fe
2020/05/20 11:29:06 Downloading file: /usr/local/models/0_FR_FR_V2.4_S2S/adaptedPrepAM/model.fe
2020/05/20 11:29:10 Failed to download: -> github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go/pipeline.NewError, /go/src/github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go/pipeline/error.go:154
HTTP request failed

Head ?timeout=601: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

Weird thing is that I can't download the old working model either.
I tried downloading older container tags (back to 2.0.0-amd64-preview ) but it's still not working.

Is there a new way of downloading custom models?
I'm following the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto?tabs=stt%2Ccsharp%2Csimple-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a breaking change to the endpoint we use to pull down the model. The team has been notified and it will be fixed next week.
We are releasing a new container today that will fix the issue. Container tag will be `2.3.1-amd64-preview`.

Full command: `docker pull containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-custom-speech-to-text:2.3.1-amd64-preview`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto?tabs=stt%2Ccsharp%2Csimple-format

If you have any other issues please file a ticket at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/